# GROUP_CONCAT to STUFF conversion returning error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this query from mysQL to SQL Server.

```
SELECT TOP 50 m.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lookup_id) as ids FROM data_lookups_ref WHERE ref_id = m.member_id and lu_type = 'prof_accr_status') as prof_accr_status_ids
FROM members m;
```

Based on other info Out there, I have converted it to this

```
SELECT TOP 50 m.*,
id_list = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + lu.lookup_id
          FROM data_lookups_ref lu
          WHERE lu.ref_id = m.member_id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM members m;
```

However I am receiving the following error.

```
ERROR: SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are
correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed
columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications
and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
Error
Code: 1934
```

Any suggestions on what have done wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the TOP working in MYSQL or you wanted to mention LIMIT instead ??

Comment: Try with `SET ARITHABORT ON;` at the start of your query. Also, take a peek [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95090/65699) to set it on by default server-wide or per database.

Comment: TT..Thanks..   getting ERROR: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ','
to data type int.
Error Code: 245 .. whe SET ARITHABORT ON;

Comment: `','+CAST(lu.lookup_id AS VARCHAR)` in the select of your subquery

Comment: Your query is fine there are some config options for sql which conflict with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 m.*,
STUFF((
      SELECT TOP 50 ',' + convert(varchar(10), lu.lookup_id)
      FROM data_lookups_ref lu
      WHERE lu.ref_id = m.member_id
      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ids
FROM members m
```

Comment: Hi Suraz.  Received following error: ERROR: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ','
to data type int.
Error Code: 245

Comment: This worked..  I just needed to cast the int to a char : SELECT TOP 50 m.*,
id_list = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10), lu.lookup_id)
          FROM data_lookups_ref lu
          WHERE lu.ref_id = m.member_id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM members m;